# Raspberry Pi | Linux | Detection of releasing a key | WASD keyboard control in C

Tags: c, linux, keyboard, raspberry-pi, release

I would like to implement a WASD control in my PI. This also works quite well so far.

```
#include "bcm2835.h"
#define SLEEPTIME   500
#define GPIO17      RPI_GPIO_P1_11
...
while(running) {    

  // get key
  printf("wait for key:");
  system("/bin/stty raw");
  key = getchar();
  system("/bin/stty cooked");
  printf(" key %i pressed!\n", key);

  // key-logic
  switch(key) {
    case 'w': 
      printf("set GPIO 17 HIGH"); 
      bcm2835_gpio_write(GPIO17, HIGH);
      bcm2835_delay(SLEEPTIME);  // <-- wanna remove this!
    break;
  }

  // reset GPIO
  bcm2835_gpio_write(GPIO17, LOW);
  printf("\n");
}
...
```

In my current implementation I have the following problem:

If I press the W key so it will be detected and sets the GPIO. After a short delay the GPIO is reset and it wait for the next key.

I want, however, that the GPIO is set as long as the W button is pressed. Do you have a hint on how I can achieve this? Is it a option that to detect a release of a key?

I have already thought of Interruputs but not found a suitable solution.
Thank you!

---

EDIT1:

I have found a solution that works great. **Many thanks to Loki Software, Inc.
with John R. Hall.**

Here you can get it: **[keycodes.c](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CHcQFjAI&url=http://taz.newffr.com/TAZ/Computer/Game/listings/fb/keycodes.c&ei=Oq-cU_CKKYyV7Abz3ICYCQ&usg=AFQjCNGZeDie91OSBJzN1I06yOL7E39bFQ&sig2=uL_mTWSIylJ4qMnRiftqTA&bvm=bv.68911936,d.ZGU)**

and here the detailed instructions: **[Programming Linux Games](http://taz.newffr.com/TAZ/Computer/Game/programming_linux_game.pdf)**

---

**EDIT2:**

I have to unfortunately withdraw my statement.
The program works under debian on a notebook. On the Rasbian with usb keyboard it will not work optimally.
While it starts without error but does not respond to the release of a key.

Does anyone know any advice?

Comment: You have to remember what you're checking for here, you're not checking for an actual button press on the keyboard, you're checking for a character being found in the input stream.  The behavior you're asking would involve interfacing with the keyboard itself.  Take a look into driver development, and hardware interfacing.  EDIT: It's also worth noting that some native libraries exist for systems that allow you to check keyboard state, I'm unsure if the pi system has one.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I'll be looking for a result in this direction lead on.

Comment: I think I have a good [solution](http://www.gcat.org.uk/tech/?p=70) found.
I'll be testing and give a feedback.

Comment: Unfortunately I had no success with the written solution. I have expanded the code with a main function and a continuous loop. Unfortunately, everything works as before. No recognition that a key has been released. Have I done something wrong?